# Navigating from silverlight to hosting asp.net

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

My app consists of Home and Map pages.
Home is ASP.NET. Map is hosting Silvellight.

How can I navigate from the Silverlight Map page to Home page?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

In Xaml you would use a `HyperLinkButton` or if you want to do direct in code use `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate` method.

**Edit**

In response to the comment just try it like this:-

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/Home.aspx" Target="_self" Content="Home" />
```

Comment: I guess my question is not clear.

Regardless whether I run my app locally in Dev environment or in production the following XAML code will navigate to the production home page.

    <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="http://mysite.com/Home.aspx" TargetName="_self"/>

Is there any way to navigate to "real" Home page.  
"http://mysite.com/Home.aspx" fro Prod environment but  
"localhost/Home.aspx" for Dev environment.

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: I hope this time it's finally clear enough :)
From http://MySite.com/Map.aspx#/Views/MyPage.xaml I would like to navigate to http://MySite.com/Home.aspx using relative navigation.
Is it possible?

Comment: @Alex:  When you discover from an answer that your question isn't clear enough you need to do two things.  __Edit__ your question to add detail and improve its quality then add a comment on the answer to indicate that you've adjusted the question.